# Flot graph is not rendered on update until i move my mouse using IE

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a problem with the flot graph http://code.google.com/p/flot/ when using Internet Explorer 9.

The problem is that when I get data after pushing a button or a link using a post or an ajax call from javascript the graph is not rendered until i move my mouse.

You can actually see the same thing on the examples page for flot:
http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html

Have any one experinced the same problem? Any solutions?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, Felix.  On my computer, IE9 shows the graph as soon as I push the button in that example.  I even used the keyboard to press the buttons (to make sure my mouse wasn't moving), still rendered right away.

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce it on my home-computer either using IE 9. I will have try this at work using another computer than my own.